# Can a valid PDF be "Java serialization data"?

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file that my reader (Zathura) would not open. I have another reader (mupdf) that does open it. I believe that Zathura depends on detecting the file magic value (first few bytes) because it can open other formats besides PDF.

On inspection, I noticed that it's detected as `Java serialisation data, version 5`.

```
$ file document.pdf
document.pdf: Java serialization data, version 5
```

Inspecting the first few bytes:

```
00000000: aced 0005 7572 0002 5b42 acf3 17f8 0608 ....ur..[B......
00000010: 54e0 0200 0078 7000 0389 9525 5044 462d T....xp....%PDF-
```

Normally a PDF would begin with `%PDF` at byte 0.

If I strip off the first 27 bytes I can open the file:

```
$ dd if=~/Downloads/file.pdf skip=27 bs=1 of=/tmp/file.pdf
```

Further inspection shows the file was generated by Apache FOP Version 1.1. I can't find any metion of this format for a PDF despite quite a bit of Google.

**Is this a valid format for a PDF ?**

---

**update** having delved a little into the header it does appear to be a java serialised array where the 'array' contains the PDF file data. I looked at the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) for the serialisation protocol and, in particular, the [grammar description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10258)  from which I could decode the 27 byte header as:

- `AC ED` = `STREAM_MAGIC` identifies the file's content as serialization protocol.
- `00 05` = `STREAM_VERSION` The serialization version.
- `75` = `TC_ARRAY`
- `72` = `TC_CLASSDESC`
- `00 02` = Length of the class name.
- `5b 42` = the class name `ur`
- `AC F3 17 F8 06 08 54 E0` = `SerialVersionUID`, the serial version identifier of the class.
- `02` = flag `SC_SERIALIZABLE` - the object supports serialization.
- `00 00` = Number of fields in this class (zero!)
- `78` = `TC_ENDBLOCKDATA`.
- `70` = `TC_NULL` (Object has no parent class).
- `00 03 89 95` = length of "array" = 231829 = size of data in bytes

The extracted PDF is indeed 231829 bytes long

```
$ dd if=document.pdf skip=27 bs=1 | wc -c
231829 bytes
```

This would indicate that the file is not corrupted and is indeed a Java serialised array that contains a PDF document. But would this be considered a valid PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) has this to say:

```
3.4.1 File Header

The first line of a PDF file is a header identifying the version of the PDF
specification to which the file conforms. For a file conforming to PDF 1.7, 
the header should be

    %PDF−1.7
```

My interpretation of that line is that strictly speaking, the file you have is **not** a valid PDF file. The first line *ends* with the correct value, but it contains additional "garbage" before it.

That beeing said, it is most likely up to the implementation of the PDF reader how to look for the `%PDF-x.x` magic, and my guess is that most read until they hit the first `0D 0A` which in your case happens to be right after the PDF-marker.

If the serialization data would have contained the `0D 0A` value, then my guess is that mupdf would also fail to read it.

Comment: I was writing the same answer, but you were just a bit quicker. I totally agree. No proper PDF reader should accept such a file as valid. That some do regardless of the extra data is sheer luck.

Comment: It's just a lone `0A` that follows the header (actually a comment line as suggested by the spec - `0a 25aa abac ad0a `) but your point makes sense as to why a more relaxed reader might cope when those adhering to the spec don't.

Comment: It seems that any combination of `0A`, `0D` or `0D 0A` works.. I have two PDF files on my desktop, and one has `0D` and the other one has `0D 0A`. :)